# How can I get all ActiveRel between two ActiveNode in Neo4j ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, neo4j, neo4j.rb

Suppose we have

- Node: `User`

  - `name` : String
- Rel: `Transaction`

  - `amount` : Float

representing a simplized Bitcoin-like transaction, where a User sends coins to other Users. A Transaction has a property `amount` which shows how much coin you're sending to the `to_node` from `from_node`.

Then now I want to get all the transactions (either uni- or bi- directionally) between Alice and Bob. How can I do this?

```
# user.rb
has_many :out, :receivers, rel_class: :Transaction
has_many :in, :senders, rel_class: :Transaction


# Console
alice = User.find_by(name: "Alice")
bob = User.find_by(name: "Bob")

# I want to do something like this:
Transaction.between(from: alice, to: bob)

# or this:
alice.receivers.rel_where(to_node: bob)
```

I was surprised that the latter isn't acceptable. It includes `bob` directly into CYPHER.

Using Neo4jrb v8.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I struggled and came to know I can do something like this:

```
alice.receivers.match_to(bob).pluck(:rel1)
```

With this we can get all the transactions sent from `alice` to `bob`, but I think it's not a good idea using the magical `:rel1` here (which is available because it is automatically written in the CYPHER, and `match_to` returns a `QueryProxy` object: [`match_to`](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/Querying.html#match-to-and-first-rel-to))

But it is always not much encouraged to get just the Rels.
Relatively, we could

```
alice.receivers.match_to(bob).rel_where(amount: 1.0)   # Txs which amount are 1.0btc
```

and

```
alice.receivers.match_to(bob).each_rel.sum {|rel| rel.amount }   # All the sent money!
```

Note that you can't do this (somehow):

```
alice.receivers.match_to(bob).rel_where("rel1.amount < 10.0")
```

but *can* go-around with this:

```
query = alice.receivers.match_to(bob)          # create just the query
query.where("#{query.rel_var}.amount < 10.0")  # you can get `:rel1` by `rel_var`
```

Comment: And now I noticed another: you can get all Rels by `rels` and only the first one by `rel`, like `alice.receivers.match_to(bob).rels`. But this can be deprecated (especially `rel`, see [this](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/697)) so it's not encouraged to do this

Comment: FYI you can pass arguments to an association to define the node / rel variables like: `alice.receivers(:node_var, :rel_var)`

Comment: @BrianUnderwood : Oh thank you, so that is the way to do it... I've looked at [the issue to add Rel querying](https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4j/issues/697), but it seemed not developed yet (and it said it would be `.where(node_var: , rel_var: )` or `where(node_var).rel(rel_var)`). Also, it returns nothing [when you go searching in the document](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/search.html?q=node_var&check_keywords=yes&area=default#).

Comment: wait, `alice.receivers(node_var: {uuid: bob.uuid}, rel_node: {amount: 1.0})` seems not to work for me. Am I missing something? Also, you cannot string query in this way..? (like `.query_as(:rel).where("rel.amount < 100")` )

Comment: `node_var` is not something that we implemented (and we probably won't).  You could either do `alice.receivers(:node_var, :rel_var).where("node_var.uuid = ? AND rel_var.amount = 1.0", bob.uuid)` or probably better `alice.receivers.where(uuid: bob.uuid).rel_where(amount: 1.0)`

Comment: For the second one you might do `alice.receivers(nil, :rel).where("rel.amount < 100")`